# Difference between running executable from disk vs removable media

Tags: permissions, windows-permissions, group-policy

I came across a strange group policy setup once and was wondering if anyone can make sense of it. We were **NOT** allowed to run executables that were stored on the local disk or network drives, but we could run executables that were on a USB mass storage device or optical media.

Essentially if you brought a USB stick with you with an executable you could run it as long as the executable resided on the stick. If you copied the executable to the local disk or a mounted network drive it would come up with that error telling you that you do not have permission.

What is the difference between running the same executable from the two places?

Comment: Just to confirm, you were allowed to use removable storage? That can also, separately, be blocked by group policy, in which case it doesn't matter whether or not you were allowed to use it for executables.

Comment: @CBHacking We were allowed to use removable storage because we would not be able to do our jobs without it. I'm aware of the GP you were talking about and we were 100% allowed to use removable storage.

Comment: If it's Windows see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/deploy-manage-removable-storage-group-policy?view=o365-worldwide Group policies has fine-grained controls. I was in a very locked-down corporate environment once where I couldn't install anything at all... except for ClickOnce .NET apps, and only if run from within the domain.  They either wanted that functionality for admin stuff, of they just forgot about it.

Comment: I am beginning to be more and more inclined to believe that it was an administrative oversight rather than an intended policy. It worked out in our favour because it made it easier to do our jobs, so no one ever said anything about it.